# Plone 5 error during creating authenticator.token

Tags: csrf, plone, authenticator

I'm using Plone 5 with an python script to change catalog. During this process I got a CSRF protection error. In Plone docs I found the following solution:

```
authenticator = context.restrictedTraverse("@@authenticator")
url = url + "?_authenticator="  + authenticator.token()
state.set(..., next_action='redirect_to:string:%s' % url)
```

Executing this Code leads to this:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
Module script, line 19, in my_script
 - <PythonScript at /path/to/my_script used for /path/library>
 - Line 19
Module plone.protect.authenticator, line 104, in token
Module plone.protect.authenticator, line 95, in createToken
Module plone.protect.authenticator, line 51, in _getKeyring
Module zope.component._api, line 169, in getUtility
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass plone.keyring.interfaces.IKeyManager>, '')
```

What went wrong?

Comment: It's best to ask Plone questions in our forum https://community.plone.org where you'll get way more eyeballs

Comment: Would be interesting to see line 19 of your script, as referenced in the err-msg. Can you provide some complete code-lines of your script for possibly reproducing the error?